# How do C1, C2, C3 relate to C and CSus4 on guitar?

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

I wanted to check some chords for ‘A Team’ by Ed Sheeran and came across [this version](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/e/ed_sheeran/the_a_team_ver22_crd.htm) which includes C1, C2, C3.

Then [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LersUZcnOiw) is called ‘How to play a C4’ but is actually how to play a CSus4

So I suppose my question is how do C1, C2, C3 relate to each other and to C and are they suspended like C4?

Comment: The person who posted the arrangement did not know exactly what to call the chords he is referring to so he made up names.  In the comments below the arrangement he points out that hovering over the chord does not show the correct fingering for what he intended.  He should have included a guide to show how to play the chords he made up names for.

Answer (score 6):

There are no chords called C1, C2, C3, or C4. In the tab the author just means different versions (voicings) of a C chord; he could as well have called them C_A, C_B, etc. One of those voicings is actually a Cadd9 chord (from low to high):

`x 3 2 0 3 3`

(the note on the third fret of the b string is a D, i.e. the 9th of C). Note that this chord is different from a C9 chord, the latter being a dominant ninth chord with a minor 7th (a Bb).

There is also no C4 chord, only a Csus4 (suspended fourth), where the third (the E) is replaced by the 4th (the F).

Ed Sheeran actually uses only two types of C chords in that song. The 'standard' open string C chord:

`x 3 2 0 1 0`

and the Cadd9 chord shown above.

Comment: I'm not sure "Cb" is a good example, someone will be asking what C flat is...

Comment: @Mr.Boy I wouldn't call it that way anyway. Just to show how arbitrary the choices C1, C2 etc. are. But thanks, I'll change it.